# How can I specify a custom MySQL socket location for installing DBD::mysql?

Tags: perl

I am trying to install `DBD::mysql`, but the installation fails with the following message:

```
--------------------
  t/00base.............................ok
  t/10connect..........................FAILED--Further testing stopped: ERROR: Access 
denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 9
    /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
  ---------------------
```

The problem is, our MySQL installation does not use the default location for the socket and will not be able to connect with the default socket. It's located somewhere else, say, at `/dspmydata/data/ourdb/mysql.sock`.

Now, how can I tell the `DBD::mysql` installer that it should use this socket instead of the default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `mysql_socket`
**Example :**

```
my $dbcon = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:database=DBNAME;mysql_socket=/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock', 'username','password');
```

**Or you can also symlink it:**

```
ln -s /mysql/tmp/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Thanks Up_One. I used the symlink.

Comment: It Worked ? Great so mark the question as Answered ! And 'One_UP' for me ! THX

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because your MySQL installation has been configured to require a password for the `root` user, not because of the location of the socket file<sup>*</sup>.

If you don't specify a user when you run the install, the name of the currently logged-in user is used. You can specify configuration details like username and password via environment variables or command line options, but for security reasons, I wouldn't recommend doing this for the `root` user.

Instead, create a test database and test user for the installation. Grant all privileges to the test user (only for the test database, of course). With the MySQL client:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 's3kr1t';
```

*(assuming the database name is `test`, the user name is `test`, and the password is `s3kr1t`)*

Export the appropriate [environment variables](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod#Environment-Variables) so that Perl can connect to the database you created, e.g.

```
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTDB=test
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTHOST=localhost
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTPASSWORD=s3kr1+
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTPORT=3306
export DBD_MYSQL_TESTUSER=test
```

and then start the installation.

---

* If Perl were unable to find the socket file, you would get an error more like this:

```
ERROR: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) 2002 Can't continue test
```